# Route Config - MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, controller

This url works:

> localhost:44366/top/ale

And this one doesn't:

> localhost:44366/top/ale/

The error:
**Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.**

Here is my Route Config:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaspx}", new { allaspx = @".*\.aspx(/.*)?" });
routes.MapRoute("ale1", "top/ale/{id}", new { controller = "Home", action = "TopAle" }, new { });
routes.MapRoute("ale2", "top/ale", new { controller = "Home", action = "TopAle" }, new { });
```

Here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult TopAle(string id=null)
{
ViewBag.Id = id;
return View("~/Top/TopApi.aspx");
}
```

Comment: trim the end forward slash in the 2nd case?

Comment: @JobesK how could I trim it?

Comment: Can you put the url in a variable then call a url.trimend('/') ?